# How can I refer to generic type specific part without supplying parts as generic themself?

Tags: typescript

I have an object defined by a type from 3rd party library:

```js
// Can't change this - part of 3rd party library; 
interface TypedEvent<
  TArgsArray extends Array<any> = any,
  TArgsObject = any
> extends Event {
  args: TArgsArray & TArgsObject;
}
```

I want to add another property to this object, which would have type of `TArgsObject`

SO far I could write it as follows:

```js
export const addParamsToEvent = <
    T extends TypedEvent<A, O>,
    A extends Array<any> = any,
    O extends any = any
>({
    args,
    ...event
}: T): TypedEvent<A, O> & { params: O } => {
    const eventWithParams = {
        ...event,
        args,
        params: Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(args).filter(
                ([key]) => typeof key === "string" || isNaN(Number(key))
            )
        ) as O,
    };

    return eventWithParams;
};
```

But I want typescript to pick A,O generic values from the argument

```js
const test = addParamsToEvent(event);
//test.params -> should pick up type
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You need to use the "infer" keyword here. You should read up on how the infer is used in extends clauses to "extract" specific type from complex types with generic arguments. In essence, careful use of the "infer" keyword can be conceptually compared to "unpacking" or "unwrapping" complex types into their inner types. Let me know if I need to write a full answer

Comment: @MichaelSohnen Would be pretty much appreciated if you can write a full answer; I tried using infer but could not get it working

Comment: Okay I will work on it soon. Answering type related questions can sometimes be difficult as need to mimic the compilation environment of the asker. Anyway, is there a chance you can make a public GitHub repo with enough code to compile and check your types?

Comment: Typings are open source and packaged at https://www.npmjs.com/package/rankify-contracts 

you can refer to 

`rankify-contracts/types/hardhat-diamond-abi/HardhatDiamondABI.sol/RankifyDiamondInstance` `VoteSubmittedEvent`

Comment: Please see what you get when you try the example event I just added to my answer

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] including some examples for `event`.  Are these going to be *annotated* as `TypedEvent<A, O>` for some `A` and `O`?  Are they going to be unannotated and just *assignable* to `TypedEvent<A, O>` for some `A` and `O` than needs to be inferred?  Right now I'm not even sure what kind of thing will have an `args` property which is both an array *and* another object type; I mean, I can imagine writing `Object.assign([1,2,3], {a: 4})` but that's not common.  If `Event` the same one from the DOM? Concrete examples will help us come up with a testable suggestion.

Comment: (see prev comment).  It's possible [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq0qkN) will do what you want, but without a [mre] of example `event`s I can't be sure.  Please [edit] with such examples and I'll take another look.  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz your approach in last comment does work for me! Many thanqqqqs!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer; in the meantime, please [edit] your question with example `event`s as I've asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `TypedEvent<A, O>` that you've shown doesn't really make it possible to easily infer `A` and `O` separately.  Given that the only place `A` and `O` appears is in the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `A & O`, the compiler will tend to infer each of them as the full type.  It's probably best to just make `addParamsToEvent()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in just `T extends TypedEvent<any, any>` (using [the intentionally loose `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to make sure anything you pass in will be accepted), and then *compute* `A` and `O` from it as necessary.  Perhaps like this:

```
export const addParamsToEvent = <
    T extends TypedEvent<any, any>,
>({
    args,
    ...event
}: T): T & {
    params: {
        [P in keyof T["args"] as P extends `${number}` | keyof any[] ? never : P]: 
        T["args"][P]
    }
} => {
    const eventWithParams = {
        ...event,
        args,
        params: Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(args).filter(
                ([key]) => typeof key === "string" || isNaN(Number(key))
            )
        )
    };
    return eventWithParams as any;
};
```

Since `T` is already essentially the same as `TypedEvent<A, O>` we can just return `T`.  Then in order to compute `O`, we can [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the `args` property of `T` and [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) any properties from that type that appear on [array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) or [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) types.  Instead of using the `Omit<T, K>`, I wrote the equivalent-ish `{[P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P}: T[P]}`, but it behaves the same.

Let's test it out:

```
declare const event: Event & { args: string[] & { a: boolean }, b: string, c: number }
const test = addParamsToEvent(event);
/* const test: Event & {
    args: string[] & {
        a: boolean;
    };
    b: string;
    c: number;
} & {
    params: {
        a: boolean;
    };
} */
```

Looks good.  The input type has some extra properties like `{b: string, c: number}`, which are preserved in the output.  And we've also intersecting with `{params: {a: boolean}}`, representing the non-array part of the `args` property of the input.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ts=5.3.2#code/PTAEGEEMDsHIBdQGMAWMDmBTU8UEsBnUAWlAAdIAnRAewDNQBmSgE3KvgE9QAbPAI0pVOAblAAoPNHiZKdSEmwAVTmUwsAogDdM0gDzjQR0EoCCldAXNDumAB4zoLItcic9MTgD5QAXlCeADSGxmYWBADy-ABWmEiI-p7iPvaOzqDauogA3iFGVJYAXCbmlq7cAGQl4VGx8SLiAL7iLeL2ZDTUyDTQBIiQLCwAClSQALYESjSZ0n6gBsYmoKm66Spqmjr6QQHQ3sFeABS5iwUEwYsAdNeYW-BNxUoAlI+gVSfGFEITxR+LRgBtIagKSgADWmE49BMAIARGdYQBdAJEYErJxEAAGABJstAAK5jfiyRqY0AAH3BkOhngByIA-KBoLdZKBikNEYU8v8lHCEYigcjmo0-D4-t1eogWdIAOp4XAjb5Efziq43O4Xf75cKarVfcYEYq1OLwS50Sg0MYaaSUPCYAiHblaozG+KXLK2+2HM5PM14HgySiO50h0CHAEQziIp6inCqTDQyN+Xz+WF9W3QdCwimUwgAOUgecOecJxKDkaeTydzqrIdrxkaDW5lEw8HxlGgyzucoVowmKN2oiaTfELDiPCo2CQPT6XayxRmiHeAXCxXTUnQdLeoGyAWK-BoNB4mBgoEagVA-DX8Az6AvSGKBKJrOa08lOHtCQCg0VBqmi8OaV4CeBpgAAKglWcZD6Bc7m3cUzmvW8t3eat8n3Q9jxgBpFkbbkr1AddMxw4wHyZUtZAaEVUMWfUfh3NC90vTCT2gEijDwkUwOAcQgA)

Answer (score 0):

The following is not tested, but hopefully it provides some conceptual help

```js
// Reexport
interface TypedEvent<
  TArgsArray extends Array<any> = any,
  TArgsObject = any
> extends Event {
  args: TArgsArray & TArgsObject;
}

// Similar to & notation
export interface TypedEventWithArgs<TArgs> extends TypedEvent {
  args:TArgs
}

export type TSpecificEvent<TEvent extends TypedEventWithArgs<any>> = TEvent extends TypedEventWithArgs<infer TArgs>? TypedEventWithArgs<TArgs> : never

export function addParamsToEvent<TEvent extends TypedEventWithArgs<any>>({
  args, ...event
}: TSpecificEvent<TEvent>){
    const eventWithParams = {
      ...event,
      args,
      params: Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(args).filter(
              ([key]) => typeof key === "string" || isNaN(Number(key))
          )
      ), // No "as" clause needed its all inferred
  };

  return eventWithParams;
}
```

Note, that for the inference to work, the "args" you supply either needs an explicit type, or needs explicit type inference using the "as const" clause

Usage:

```js
const myEvent = {args:["some","array","of","args"]} as const
const myModifiedEvent = addParamsToEvent(myEvent)
```

Comment: This yields to return type of params be 
```[k: string]: unknown;
```

Provided argument is type of `TypedEvent` with generic values provided

Comment: @Peersky You need to explicitly type your "event" variable, so something like `const event = {...some stuff...} as const`, or `const event: {my specific event type} = {...some stuff...}`. Please add an explicitly typed "event" variable to your original question

Comment: Im trying to avoid any extra code in the implementation, if forced to do so Im happy enough with just returning value as T for autocomplete even thought it will be potentially missleading.

Comment: @Peersky It's up to you. Typescript's automatic type inference is very rudimentary and works best for primitive types. For more complex types, if you are truly invested in type inference, you need the "as const" or explicit typing as mentioned. Typescript is not meant to be a super-detailed inference engine